# Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined (Jquery - Datatable)

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo una `datatable` que procesa todo del lado del servidor:

```
 var table = $("#dt_tasks").DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": 'url'
                },
                "columns": [ ... ]
             });
```

Cuando la tabla está vacía, agrego un registro y la tabla se refresca automáticamente con el siguiente código:

```
$("#frmCreateTmTasks").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataFrm = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: dataFrm,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (data) {\
        loadTmTasksTable();\
    });
});
```

Ahora, yo en la tabla tengo un botón acción para editar y eliminar cada fila.

Cuando agrego un registro y quiero editar o eliminar ese registro me tira el error:

> Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined

pero si aprieto `f5` y vuelvo a cargar la página, el editar y eliminar funciona.

El código para obtener los datos para  editar y eliminar son similares, y acá es donde tira el error si no actualizo la página:

```
$("#dt_tm_tasks tbody").on("click", "a.edit", function () {

   //ACA ESTA EL PROBLEMA!!!!
   var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

   $("#frmEditTmTasks #id_tm_task").val(data.id);
   $("#frmEditTmTasks #product").val(data.product);

   $("#frmEditTmTasks #event").append('<option value="' + data.calendar.event.id + '" hidden selected> ' + data.calendar.event.event + '</option>');
   $("#frmEditTmTasks #calendar").append('<option value="' + data.calendar.id + '" hidden selected> ' + data.calendar.start_date + ' al ' + data.calendar.end_date + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: cual es el código que contiene `loadTmTasksTable();`? o mejor dicho que lineas de código estas usando para refrescar la tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tu problema sea que no estas haciendo la peticion al servidor al refrescar para eso puedes usar:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

este utiliza las mismas propiedades que están declaradas en el `datatables` [aquí mas ejemplos](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29#Examples)

también puedes usar:

```
table.ajax.url("URL").load();
```

este obtiene la informacion de la url y remplaza la existente en la tabla así como también remplaza la url puesta en las propiedades del `datatables` [aquí mas ejemplos](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()#Example)

Answer (score 0):

Para refrescar una tabla hecha con `dataTables` yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:
`$('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
$("#frmCreateTmTasks").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataFrm = $(this).serialize();
    $('#dt_tm_tasks').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```